# Do the array update after the function is executed in the array? if not can someone explain me why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I just wondering if the **array** is updated after the **checking_plus_1** is running

```
for(let i = array.length-1;i>0;i--){
    if(k < test.length){
        checking_plus_1(combine,array,test[k])
        if(array[i] == 100 && array[i-1] == 100){
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[i-1] = array[j-1];
            array[j] = test[k];
            array[j-1] = test[k];
            combine[j] = test[k];
            combine[j-1] = test[k];
            changeRowtoZero_minus_1(combine,array,i,i-1)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite I don't know your `checking_plus_1` function, yes you can mutate your array in your for loop on each iteration.

You can also see the changes by adding `console.log(array)` in your for loop.